# ipgeo plugin errors

Tags: ee2, plugin, ip

Installing the Clive Zagno [IPGEO](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ipgeo) third-party plugin to EE2 third_party folder, my web page embededded with {exp:ipgeo:country} gives out "webpage not available" error. I tried debugging; however not to any success, any help here will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Diwakar

Comment: It looks like this add-on hasn't been updated since 2011, so there's a good chance it's not compatible with current versions of EE.

Comment: Also providing a sample of your code would help.